# Live Wallpaper touch - I don't want it when an app is launched

Tags: android

I'm listening out for touches in my live wallpaper.

It's all great, except, I don't want it to be triggered if an icon / app was launched during the touch.

Is this possible?

Richard

Comment: I don't think so, least I haven't found a way so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of one method that might work.  It would be to use `android.app.ActivityManager` or one of its nested classes.   I've never used it before, but I assume information about recently launched apps might be contained in it.